# SQL 2005 Reduce Table Large Table size with 0 Records

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hey I have some temp tables which hold data and then gets deleted after. I was just checking the size of these tables and eventough they currently have 0 records in them they are very large in size.

SQL 2005 DB

How Can I reduce the size of these tables ?

Comment: How do I do that ? I dont see an "Accept" button anywhere on my previous questions.

Comment: click the check mark in the upper left of the answer that is best.

Comment: Ok done ! Sorry never noticed that arrow before !

Comment: Is that ok now or..? Just wondering if this thread is locked to people perhaps ?

Answer (score 2):

Since there are zero rows, the easiest way to do this is to drop and recreate the table.

You can use `dbcc shrinkdatabase` or `dbcc shrinkfile`, however you can't shrink a single table unless it is stored in its own a file group.

This "reserved space" that you want to remove can be used for the next new data added to that table, without the database needing to reserve any the next time you  insert data.  If you remove the space and then insert many rows, the need to allocate this back again will add a little more overhead to the insertion of that new data.

I would not do anything with this empty unused reserved space unless you are really short of disk space.  If you need more disk space then it might be better to get more than to constantly need to micromanage this table's disk space.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server won't actually release the page until later.  Do an index rebuild (not a defrag) on the table, and that should release the free space back to the database.